# eslint + jsconfig + nextjs module path aliases (absolue path import - @)

Tags: reactjs, import, next.js, eslintrc, nestjs-config

I am trying to import the files using custom aliases following the [nextjs documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases).

My current approach is

from

```
import Header from '../../../components/Header';
```

to

```
import Header from '@components/Header';
```

I am getting the expected result. But eslint throws the following error:

- unable to resolve path to module (eslint - import/no unresolved)

And I have tried adding the following line in my eslintrc file to resolve the error

```
    settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: ['src'],
      },
    },
  },
```

But still the eslint throws the same error.

What is the correct approach to resolve this one?

Thanks in advance...

Note: I don't want to remove eslint and I need @components import aliases

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally after digging into lots of GitHub answers and etc...

Inside your eslintrc file... add the following aliases

```
    settings: {
    'import/resolver': {
      alias: {
        map: [
          ['@components', '../../../components/'],
          ['@images', '../../../assets/images/'],
        ],
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
      },
    },
  },
```

and also to fix flow error
inside your flowconfig file add the name_mapper

```
module.name_mapper='^@components' ->'<PROJECT_ROOT>/../../../components'
module.name_mapper='^@images' ->'<PROJECT_ROOT>/../../../assets/images'
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to also install `npm i -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript` and then add below to eslint config file:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {} // this loads <rootdir>/tsconfig.json to eslint
    },
}
```

> Reference: https://gourav.io/blog/nextjs-cheatsheet

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding your custom paths in `tsconfig.json`/`jsconfig.json`, like so:

- Add a `baseUrl` in your `compilerOptions` (in my case it's `"baseUrl": "."`)
- Add your paths in a `paths` object:

```
"paths": {
   "components": ["components/*"],
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks.
Yes I am doing the same. But i am facing the eslint error. How to fix the lint error

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the problem by the means described above.

However, we were able to solve the problem using the following library.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-alias

```
npm install eslint-plugin-import eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev
```

jsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
    }
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
...
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "alias": {
        "map": [["@", "./src"]],
        "extensions": [".ts", ".js", ".jsx", ".json"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

import example

```
import Header from '../components/Header';

to

import Header from '@/components/Header';
```